# How can I connect snort and snorby in docker environment?

Tags: docker, snort

I'm going to have simple presentation showing the concept of IDS/IPS

To deploy as soon, comfortable as possible, I was trying to take advantage of container - docker.

So, I chose two docker images - [polinux/snorby](https://hub.docker.com/r/polinux/snorby/) and [million12/mariadb](https://hub.docker.com/r/million12/mariadb/).

As manual image maintainer provided, I tried.

Finally, I could make login page show up, but couldn't go further.
Cannot login, just stuck this page.

command I used is :

```
docker run -d --name snorby-db -p 3306:3306 --env="MARIADB_USER=snorbyuser" --env="MARIADB_PASS=password" million12/mariadb && \
docker run -d --name snorby -p 80:80 --env="DB_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1:3306" --env="DB_USER=snorbyuser" --env="DB_PASS=password" polinux/snorby -e development -p 80
```

How can I login and see the logs collected by snort daemon?

At least, where can I have reference to fix this up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command to connect into a container:

```
docker exec -it <container name> bash
```

The default password for Snorby:

- Username: snorby@snorby.org
- Password: snorby

or

- user : snorby@example.com
- password :snorby